# How DDNS can link to 3G simcard dynamic IP

Tags: google, domains, html, redirects, dns

I have CCTV that work via 3G (use simcard). I can access it directly using dynamic IP but as it keep changes, I won't be able to access it. My question if I set DDNS on CCTV, how can DDNS detect the current dynamic IP. Where do I port forward the DDNS host name as there is no router use. scenario like this

CCTV(3G simcard)  ------> 3G provider ------> user
                  <------             <------

Comment: Questions here are required to be about operating a [website under your control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so this is being closed as it appears to be in regards to a CCTV and network issue.

Answer (score 1):

The CCTV software that uses the 3G will need to support DDNS and from what you say that is the case. You now need a DDNS provider... personally I recommend [**DynDNS**](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-pro/) which offer some of the best DNS solutions that are reliable and not to expensive. I recommend the pro package which in their own short description sounds exactly what you need:

> Looking to access your computer, DVR, webcam or camera system remotely
>   without having to remember a confusing (and ever changing) IP address?
>   Try DynDNS Pro, a great option for those who need Dynamic DNS and
>   Remote Access capabilities without any bells, whistles or fireworks.

There are many other DDNS providers however and you should take a look here for [free DDNS and other paid DDNS services](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/). If the CCTV system is important I recommend a paid service as they have a habit of stop working on free based DDNS

Answer (score 0):

There's never a "DDNS provider knows my IP!" situation. It is the endpoint device holding your actual nated (almost for sure private) IP who connects to DDNS provider instead.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make a port forwarding from the router ( located in 3G ISP ) and this is a challenge !

Comment: Welcome to pro webmasters.  For this to be a useful answer, please provide any additional information that could help people with this question such as instructions for enabling port forwarding or links to documentation about enabling port forwarding.